# Where can I download a list of all stocks traded on NYSE, AMEX, NASDAQ that includes dividend and dividend yield information

Tags: dividends, price, nasdaq, nyse, ftp

Looking for a site I can download common stock information that includes dividend information as well as price.  I see reference to NASDAQ stock screener but I don't see that information there.

Comment: What is the purpose of downloading the data? Do you need to select few stocks, which pays dividends or do you need to download data from a lot of stocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to convey an answer as best as possible.

**One method of screening for dividend paying stocks**: If you do not know which stocks you want to work with, you can use a stock-screener like [Tradingview stock screener](https://www.tradingview.com/screener/). Here you can filter for dividend paying stocks (from high to low) and then single out your preferable exchanges (under the advanced filter section).

**Downloading from Yahoo finance:**
Let's assume that you've found your selection of stocks and now want to download the information (dividends and prices/adj.prices). This can be done on [Yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/). Search for your stock, go to historical data and specify your time-period. There should be a download button. Under "Show" you can filter for "dividends only" and download an excel spreadsheet with the dividends under the same period.

**Downloading from Alphavantage.co**: Assuming that you have a bit of coding experience, you can get even more stock-data from [Alpha Vantage](https://www.alphavantage.co/) via Python or R. Here, you have "5 API requests per minute and 500 requests per day" as a free user and you can request for an API key for free. As an example, you can find the dividends and general time-series information of a stock (Apple is used as an example) via the function call:

**Update 22-10-2022:** TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED is now only for premium users.

```
library(alphavantager)
library(httr)

av_api_key(YOUR API KEY HERE)


#Get time-series data (DAILY)
AAPL <- as.data.frame(av_get(symbol = "AAPL", av_fun = "TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED", 
outputsize = "full"))
rownames(AAPL) <- AAPL$timestamp
head(AAPL)

#Getting general company information:
temp <- GET("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=AAPL&apikey=YOUR API KEY HERE")

AAPL_companyinfo <- content(temp)

#getting general information on Apple (disregarding basic information). 
AAPL_companyinfo <- t(as.data.frame(AAPL_companyinfo[-c(1,2,3,4)]))
```

Which gives you:

[image: General Time-series information]
[image: General Company information]

In order to understand the API calls/functions, I recommend you to look at the documentation on the Alphavantage website and the "alphavantager" package description. In general, the av_get function returns the adjusted time-series including high, low, open,
close, adj.close, dividend amount, and split-coefficient. I used the "httr" package to scrape the content of the webpage in the "GET" function. This is just a JSON file and essentially, you could open the website, right-click and save as a .json file (as an alternative way to get the data).

Hopefully, this helps or give inspiration for alternative solutions/answers by others.

Answer (score 0):

FINVIZ offers a number of screeners.  If you don't mind a close approximation of the dividend, you can use the FINANCIAL screener.  I say close approximation because it provides the percent yield in two decimals.  When you multiply the yield times share price, you may be off a penny or two from the actual dividend.

The screener includes a number of filters if you want to find specific lists (sector, optionable stocks, industry, country etc.).

If you want the precise dividend as well as the ex-div date, google dividend calendar.  I have found the NASDAQ and ZACKS to be reliable.